# Selecionar os dados de duas tabelas para exibir em uma coluna?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, join

Considere as tabelas para o cadastro de clientes :

**Tabela Pessoa**

```
|ID|NOME|TIPO|EMAIL|
```

**Tabela Pessoa Fisica**

```
|ID|CPF|
```

**Tabela pessoa Juridica**

```
|ID| CNPJ| inscricao_municipal| inscricao_estadual|
```

Meu objetivo e consultar os dados de todas as pessoas ,a principio utilizei a seguinte instrução :

```
SELECT cnpj , cpf, nome , email
from pessoa
left join pessoa_juridica on pessoa.id = pessoa_juridica.id
left join pessoa_fisica on pessoa.id   = pessoa_fisica.id
```

**Resultado** :

```
| CPF | CNPJ | nome | email | inscricao_estadual |inscrição_municipal |
```

como posso exibir o **CNPJ** e **CPF** na mesma coluna ?

**Exemplo :**

```
|CPF / CNPJ | nome | email | inscricao_estadual | inscrição_municipal |
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce).

```
COALESCE(pessoa_juridica.CNPJ, pessoa_fisica.CPF)
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado ! funcionou aqui !

Comment: Interessante esse Coalesce +1